# Why does pointcloud pointing upwards?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a camera remotely and sending the compressed image frames to host pc. I am using RTABmap to create a 2d MAP.

The problem occurs when the PCL is being published and the points are located above my robot. Why is that? Have a look at the picture:
[image: image description]

My TF is normal and I am using this CPP code to send the images:

https://github.com/duo3d/duo3d_driver/blob/master/src/duo3d_driver.cpp

And using this launch file with static TF:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="pi/2" value="1.5707963267948966" />
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="duo3d_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 01 /duo3d/camera_frame duo3d_camera 100" />

    <node name="duo3d" pkg="duo3d_driver" type="duo3d_driver" output="screen">
        <param name="frame_rate" value="30.0"/>
        <rosparam param="image_size">[320, 240]</rosparam>
        <param name="dense3d_license" value="OVMZU-ZHFE2-9K41K-NQL44-WX3DV"/>
        <param name="gain" value="0"/>
        <param name="exposure" value="50"/>
        <param name="auto_exposure" value="true"/>
        <param name="vertical_flip" value="true"/>
        <param name="led" value="35"/>
        <param name="processing_mode" value="1"/>
        <param name="image_scale" value="0"/>
        <param name="pre_filter_cap" value="8"/>
        <param name="num_disparities" value="7"/>
        <param name="sad_window_size" value="3"/>
        <param name="uniqueness_ratio" value="2"/>
        <param name="speckle_window_size" value="256"/>
        <param name="speckle_range" value="2"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="rqt_gui" type="rqt_gui" name="rqt_gui" args="--perspective-file $(find duo3d_driver)/launch/rqt/depth_view.perspective"/>
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find duo3d_driver)/launch/rviz/depth.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

So why does PCL prints on top of my robot? That makes my map to be occupied everywhere.

Also, this is what PCL of obstacles look like produced by RTABMAP:

[image: image description]

I am using default stereo_mapping launch file.

EDIT!
It seems to do something with IMU but I do not know yet what is happening. When I tilt my IMU, pcl also tilts.
If you can debug together with me that would be great.

My rosbag is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qRQrpndWqA_F7vqKuDCZKGiTedbIf4-S/view?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319313/why-does-pointcloud-pointing-upwards?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems there is a missing optical rotation TF. You may try this:

```
<arg name="pi/2" value="1.5707963267948966" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="duo3d_base_link" args="0 0 0 -$(arg pi/2) 0 -$(arg pi/2) /duo3d/camera_frame duo3d_camera 100" />
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2019-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-24**:
@matlabbe Hi, thank you. Indeed, there is a problem with the tf but I fixed that by assigning PCL values in a different order: pcl.x = z and etc., as static_tf did not fix the problem. I guess I need to send TF myself.
Also, when I send compressed images without RTABmap I get 30 Hz but as soon as I turn on RTABmap, my frequency of images drop to 10 Hz, do you know the reason?

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-24**:
@matlabbe Actually, if you can have a look at my new question I would appreciate:
https://answers.ros.org/question/319346/all-spaces-are-occupied-using-rtabmap-stereo/

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-31**:
Make sure you changed `frame_id` of rtabmap from `duo3d_camera` to `/duo3d/camera_frame`. If you don't start rtabmap, it is maybe because there are no subscribers on the topic images, so they are not compressed (thus no processing time used to compress image)